# How to sort MySQL results by most matches when using LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

I´m currently working on a query that must show a list of all articles from a specific table, but it must sort the list according to a search form, so that the articles that contain most/best matches are shown first and those that do not have any matches at all will be shown last sorted alphabetically.

I have made this code which is working fine, though I cannot find a way to sort the matches by most hits / relevance.

Here is my code:

```
$search = $_POST["searhwords"];
$search = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$search);

$SearchQueryArray = str_replace(",", "", $search);
$SearchQueryArray = str_replace(" ", ",", $SearchQueryArray);
$SearchQueryArray = explode(',', $SearchQueryArray);


$outputtt1 = '';
$outputtt2 = '';
foreach ( $SearchQueryArray as $queryword )
{
    $outputtt1 .= "title LIKE '%".$queryword."%' OR ";  
    $outputtt2 .= "title NOT LIKE '%".$queryword."%' AND ";  
}

$outputtt1 = rtrim($outputtt1, ' OR ');
$outputtt2 = rtrim($outputtt2, ' AND ');




$query_for_result = mysql_query("SELECT * from mytable 
WHERE ".$outputtt1."
union all
SELECT * from mytable 
WHERE ".$outputtt2."
");
```

So I need to find a way to sort the article that contain matches so that those that contain most matches are sorted first.

You can see the script i Have made live here:
http://www.genius-webdesign.com/test/querytest.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the SQL that does this:

```
select t.*
from mytable
order by ((title like '%keyword1%') +
          (title like '%keyword2%') +
          (title like '%keyword3%') +
          . . .
          (title like '%keywordn%')
         ) desc;
```

MySQL treats boolean expressions as numbers, with true being `1`.  So, this counts the number of matches.

By the way, if your data has any size, you might find full text search is more efficient than using `like`.

EDIT:

Counting the number of keywords is a bit more challenging, but you can do it as:

```
order by ((length(replace(title, 'keyword1', 'x')) -
           length(replace(title, 'keyword1', '')
          ) +
          (length(replace(title, 'keyword2', 'x')) -
           length(replace(title, 'keyword2', '')
          ) +
          . . .
          (length(replace(title, 'keywordn', 'x')) -
           length(replace(title, 'keywordn', '')
          )
         );
```

Counting the number of appearance of a keyword is more cumbersome than merely looking for where or not it is present.

Comment: This does not seem to work.
Here is the modified query with example data:
<code>
$query_for_result = mysql_query("select t.*
from zt8zo_content
order by ((title like '%word1%') + 
          (title like '%word2%') + 
          (title like '%word3%')) desc;
union all
SELECT * from zt8zo_content 
WHERE title NOT LIKE '%word1%' AND 
      title NOT LIKE '%word2%' AND 
      title NOT LIKE '%word3%'
");
</code>
This does not work, unfortunately

Comment: @GeniusDesign . . . I'm not sure what the query in your comment has to do with the query in my solution.  You don't need a `union all`.  Just one query with an `order by` clause as specified in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the implementation. Will check again.

Comment: Thanks alot, I modified your query a little and now it works as I wanted it to. Heres is the query I now use:

"select *
from zt8zo_content
order by ( (title like '%word1%') + 
           (title like '%word2%') + 
           (title like '%word3%') 
) desc"

Comment: There is one very small detail that is not 100% as wanted..
If you go to the demo-link i posted and search "folio template" you will see that number #2 results should actually be placed as number #1, because the word "folio" is matched 2 times in result #2

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do it using full-text search

```
SELECT *, 
  MATCH('title') AGAINST($_GET['query']) * 10 as score1, 
  MATCH('content') AGAINST($_GET['query']) * 5 AS score2
FROM articles
WHERE MATCH (title, content) AGAINST($_GET['query'])
ORDER BY (score1) + (score2) DESC;
```

Alter your table like this if needed

```
ALTER TABLE articles ENGINE = MYISAM;
ALTER TABLE articles ADD FULLTEXT(title, content);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Though I prefer using LIKE in this particular case because the queries will be pretty light.

Comment: @GeniusDesign That's fine. Maybe one day someone else would find this useful ;)

Comment: @hex494D49 "one day" has come!